# how to detect if --quiet option is specified with rake

Tags: ruby, rake

how to detect of if --quiet option is specified with rake.

Intention is to filter custom messages based on category.

```
class Category
  INFO = 1
  WARNING = 2
  ERROR = 3
end

@trace = true

task :silent do
  @trace = false
end

def trace(msg, category=Category::INFO)
  return if (@trace == nil)
  return if ((@trace == false) && (category == Category::INFO))
  puts msg
end
```

In this case I would like to add one more case to filter out trace if --quiet option is specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rake.verbose provides option to check if --quiet mode is specified

Following simple rake file like produces output like this
$rake --quiet
false

$rake default

```
task :default do
  puts Rake.verbose
end
```

It is also possible to override the setting within rakefile using Rake.verbose(true|false)

Comment: I have a `private method 'verbose' called for Rake:Module` error

Comment: Looks like the proper way is do it like this: `Rake.application.options.verbose`

Comment: There are also `Rake.application.options.silent` and `Rake.application.options.quiet` which correspond to `--silent` and `--quiet` respectively.

Comment: I couldn't get `Rake.application.options.quiet` to be anything other than `nil` for me.

Comment: @Dimitar, if you have made an answer of this I would have voted for it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just call the method `verbose` in rake-10.0.4, at least.

With a task:

```
task :default do
  puts verbose
end
```

I get:

```
$ rake --silent
false
$ rake --quiet
false
$ rake --verbose
true
```