# How to detect if the makefile `--silent/--quiet` command line option was set?

Tags: makefile

How to detect if the makefile **`--silent`** / **`--quiet`** command line options was set?

Related questions:

1. [how to detect if --quiet option is specified with rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494693/how-to-detect-if-quiet-option-is-specified-with-rake)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need:

```
$(findstring s,$(word 1, $(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

Because MAKEFLAGS has long options, too, eg:

```
MAKEFLAGS=s -j80 --jobserver-auth=4,6
```

So, IOW:

```
 # Set SILENT to 's' if --quiet/-s set, otherwise ''.
 SILENT := $(findstring s,$(word 1, $(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call either **`make --quiet`** or **`--silent`**, the variable **`{MAKEFLAGS}`** is set only to **`s`**. And if you add other options like **`--ignore-errors`** and **`--keep-going`**, the variable **`{MAKEFLAGS}`** is set to **`iks`**. Then, you can capture it with this:

```shell
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    printf 'Calling with "%s" %s\n' "${MAKECMDGOALS}" "${MAKEFLAGS}";

    if [[ "ws" == "w$(findstring s,${MAKEFLAGS})" ]]; then \
        printf '--silent option was set\n'; \
    fi
```

References:

1. [Recursive make: correct way to insert `$(MAKEFLAGS)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611004/recursive-make-correct-way-to-insert-makeflags)
2. [How to set MAKEFLAGS from Makefile, in order to remove default implicit-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781706/how-to-set-makeflags-from-makefile-in-order-to-remove-default-implicit-rules)
3. [Remove target from MAKECMDGOALS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443920/remove-target-from-makecmdgoals)
4. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/The-Make-Macro-MAKEFLAGS.html

Answer (score 1):

```
make            gives  MAKEFLAGS = ""
make -j8        gives  MAKEFLAGS = " -j8 --jobserver-auth=3,4"
make -j8 -s     gives  MAKEFLAGS = "s -j8 --jobserver-auth=3,4"
make -j8 -s -B  gives  MAKEFLAGS = "Bs -j8 --jobserver-auth=3,4"
```

So this should do the trick:

```
$(findstring s,$(filter-out -%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

It returns "s" or an empty string, which is suitable as the condition for an `$(if ...)`.